# What is collection and what is member?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is collection and what is member?

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get :preview
  end
end
```

## vs

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one let you request [GET]:

```
/photos/1/preview

# action 'preview' within PhotosController with params[:photo_id] == 1
```

The second one let you request [GET]:

```
/photos/search

# action 'search' within PhotosController
```